# How to Add Network Analyst dll in My Web Mapping Application adf?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, web-mapping, arcgis-web-adf

I'm a beginner in ArcGIS & I'm shooting blind really.  I want to add the Network Analyst tool box to find the shortest path in my project. I tried this solution:

I can't add Network Analyst dll to my web mapping application. I use ArcGIS 10 & Visual Studio 10 and I used web application adf to build my website. I tried the Network Analyst toolbox or networkanalyst.dll from developer kit folder but an error occurs:

> The dll not found.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you give proper permission to  the folder ? what is the error message exactly ?

Comment: Do you have a Network Analyst license?

Comment: Please check this http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/adf/dotnet/developer/ADF/common_problems.htm and refer 4th problem..might be useful for you

Comment: Fezter
i can use in Arcmap without problem

Answer (score 1):

that is the error message
"there are no cmponents in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\DeveloperKit10.0\DotNet\ESRI.ArcGIS.NetworkAnalyst.dll' that can be place on toolbox"